# Visual Basic equivalent of C# type check

Tags: c#, vb.net

What is the Visual Basic equivalent of the following C# boolean expression?

```
data.GetType() == typeof(System.Data.DataView)
```

Note: The variable `data` is declared as `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Have you tried an online converter, such as http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Answer (score 81, accepted):

As I recall

```
TypeOf data Is System.Data.DataView
```

Edit:
As James Curran pointed out, this works if data is a subtype of System.Data.DataView as well.

If you want to restrict that to System.Data.DataView only, this should work:

```
data.GetType() Is GetType(System.Data.DataView)
```

Comment: Note, however, if the VB "is" is anyhting like the C# "is", that would be true if data is a DataView or derived from DataView.  The original code would only be true if data was specifically a DataView object.

Comment: @James Curran:  Good point, I've updated it with the other way I know of to check that (ironically, the way I originally had it before editing)

Comment: @James: VB’s `Is` is actually identical to `object.ReferenceEquals`. But `Typeof … Is` indeed equals C#’s `is` operator.

Comment: This seems to work fine in Visual Studio, but at dotnetfiddle.net, the first piece of code causes a compilation error, saying, "<typename> is a class type and cannot be used as an expression."  Is there something you technically have to import to use the first type of comparison, which Visual Studio imports automatically?

Answer (score 42):

Just thought I'd post a summary for the benefit of C# programmers:

#### C# `val is SomeType`

In VB.NET: `TypeOf val Is SomeType`

Unlike `Is`, this can only be negated as `Not TypeOf val Is SomeType`

#### C# `typeof(SomeType)`

In VB.NET: `GetType(SomeType)`

#### C# `val.GetType() == typeof(SomeType)`

In VB.NET: `val.GetType() = GetType(SomeType)`

(although `Is` also works, see next)

#### C# `val.ReferenceEquals(something)`

In VB.NET: `val Is something`

Can be negated nicely: `val IsNot something`

---

#### C# `val as SomeType`

In VB.NET: `TryCast(val, SomeType)`

#### C# `(SomeType) val`

In VB.NET: `DirectCast(val, SomeType)`

(except where types involved implement a cast operator)

Comment: Be very, very careful with the casts. They are not strictly equivalent to the C# versions (there's no real way to get full C# cast semantics in VB).

Answer (score 3):

You could also use **TryCast** and then check for nothing, **this way you can use the casted type later on**. **If you don't need to do that, don't do it this way, because others are more efficient.**

See this example:

**VB:**

```
    Dim pnl As Panel = TryCast(c, Panel)
    If (pnl IsNot Nothing) Then
        pnl.Visible = False
    End If
```

**C#**

```
Panel pnl = c as Panel;
if (pnl != null) {
    pnl.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: @Teejay please explain

Comment: `TryCast` is really unefficient in comparison with methods explained in Powerlord answer!

Comment: @Teejay So it is better to remove my answer?

Comment: I don't think you should. You answer is not incorrect, but it's not what OP requested: they only wanted to do a type check, but you went beyond by casting the object (which may not be necessary). If you had needed the casted object, then `TryCast` or `as` would have been OK.

Comment: Maybe you should only emphasize the sentence *this way you can use the casted type later on*.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
GetType(Foo)
```